# MixPanelでユーザ毎に行動を管理したい

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

MixPanelのJavaScript APIを使用して、ユーザごとに行動を管理したいと考えています。

以下のマニュアルのManaging user identityを参考に行っているのですが、ユーザ毎にフィルタすることができません。
https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript

どのように行えば実現できるかご存知ないでしょうか？

### 追記

mixpanelで設定しているコードは以下です。（仮で固定データを入れてます
ブラウザを更新するとView Page testがIncrementされると思うのですが、MixPanelのPeopleのメニューには何も変化が現れなくて困っています。

具体的にやりたい事は例のView page testをユーザ情報毎にフィルタする事です。

```
 mixpanel.identify("11111");
 mixpanel.people.set({
     "$id": "11111",
     "$email": "hoge@email.com",    // only special properties need the $
     "vpc":0
 });
 mixpanel.people.increment("vpc");
```

Comment: 再現情報をもっとシェアすることはできますか? ユーザーIDを設定しているコードや、期待するようなフィルタリングができていない画面のスクリーンショットやコードなど (バグ報告を書くような感じで)。

Comment: ありがとうございます、追記します！

Comment: ユーザーIDを設定するAPIは、 identity ではなくて identi**f**y ですね。実際のコードでも identity になっていますか? (コピペミスではなく)

Comment: 申し訳ありません。typoでした。実際のコードと同じにしました

Comment: 自己解決しましたので、一旦クローズにさせて頂きます。対応いただきましてありがとうございました！

Comment: 解決されてよかったです。もしよければ、解決した方法など自分で回答を書いて、後でチェックマークを入れておいていただけると、他の方の参考になると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。そうさせて頂きます！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました

原因はPeopleに追加したプロパティの確認方法が間違えていたことでした

mixpanelのPeople→Explore→ユーザの詳細ページで確認しなければならないようでユーザ一覧からは確認できませんでした。

また、以下のコードだと読みこむ度にVPCが0に初期化されるので１以上になることはありません。

```
mixpanel.identify("11111");
mixpanel.people.set({
    "$id": "11111",
    "$email": "hoge@email.com",    // only special properties need the $
    "vpc":0
});
mixpanel.people.increment("vpc");
```

以上です